# Greens Function, point charge spherical box

Tags: electrostatics, greens-functions

I`m an engineering physics student but I recently got involved in a Mathematical Physics Contest for Masters degree in Physics. I really struggled with this problem and couldn’t solve it, the professor is a shady russian guy that doesn’t like sharing much :/

Any of you have any ideas how to solve it?  Or maybe books where I could find it ( maybe I ought to learn russian because I haven’t found a single book that has this problem yet)

I only got to the harmonic Bessel functions because that’s where most of the textbooks go to, but here we got $Y_m$'s , $J_l$'s, factorials and a triple sum.

This is how it goes:
Consider a point charge at ($r'$, $\theta'$, $\phi'$) inside an earthed 'spherical box defined by the surface $r=a$,
show that the potential inside this spherical box is given by:

$$\psi(r, \theta, \phi)=G\left(\vec{r}, \overrightarrow{r'}\right)=\frac{4}{a^{2}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^{l} \sum_{l=0}^{\infty} (2 l+1) \frac{(l-m) !}{(l+m) !} \frac{1}{\left[J_{l+\frac{1}{2}}^{\prime}\left(\alpha_{l n}\right)\right]^{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{r r^{\prime}}} J_{l+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{\alpha_{l n}}{a} r\right)J_{l+\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{\alpha_{l n}}{a} r^{\prime}\right) Y_{l}^{m}(\theta, \phi) Y_{l}^{m}\left(\theta, \phi^{\prime}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Poisson's equation means that the potential is a Green's function of the Laplacian. Green's functions for a differential operator have an "eigenfunction expansion" that looks like

$$G(\vec{r},\vec{r}\,')=\sum_\lambda\frac{{\psi_\lambda}^*(\vec{r}\,')\psi_\lambda(\vec{r})}{\lambda}$$

where $\psi_\lambda$ is an eigenfunction of the same operator with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

So you first solve for the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the Laplacian inside a sphere, with boundary conditions that they are finite at the origin and vanish on the sphere. In spherical coordinates, this will give spherical Bessel functions of the first kind in $r$ times spherical harmonics in $\theta$ and $\phi$.

The numerator in the eigenfunction expansion will give you the stuff in your equation starting with $1/\sqrt{rr'}$.

The stuff before that must be coming from the eigenvalues and the normalization of the eigenfunctions.

The triple sum is the sum over the eigenfunctions, which in three dimensions inside a sphere will be enumerated by integers $n$, $l$, and $m$.

Note: My eigenfunction $\psi$ is not your potential $\psi$.

Also: I think there should be a $*$ (complex conjugate) on one of your spherical harmonics. Otherwise, I don't think your potential will be real.

I think your class may be using a different normalization of spherical harmonics than I’m used to. I wouldn’t expect to see those factorials with $l$ and $m$.